# SVG Optimization: Strip SVG classes, merge styles into XML props

Tags: svg, inkscape

I'm using Inkscape to handle SVG images and I've noticed it generates several ".a" classes for the styles.

This is causing issues on other SVGs on my webpage, and I found no option on Inkscape's exporting options to merge these props, so I'm wondering if there's an automatized way to strip those declarations and transform the classes into XML properties for each path (no need to be related to Inkscape itself).

Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you tried running  your SVGs through [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo)? You can test the different options (e.g. "Style to attributes") here: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

Comment: @Sphinxxx Yup, I just gave it a try, but it ended messing with the icons. I think I'll have to do I manually